# Android studio error This support library should not use a lower version (19)

Tags: android

I created the project then error message:

```
Error:(23, 12) This support library should not use a lower version (19) than the targetSdkVersion (20)
```

error code is here: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20+'
```

first open SDK Manager and update the support Libary.
or change the targetSDKVersion to 19

the filename is 'build.gradle'

Comment: For future problem, change the "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'" to "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:targetSDKVersionNumber+'". At least, this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools--> Android--> SDK Manager --> SDK Tools tab --> Android Support Library --> look at the **Version**

then go to Project view--> YourProject -->app --> build.gradle --> change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:yourLatestVersion'
```

Android Support Library version must be replaced to the latest version you have in your SDK. Note that your `targetSDKVersion` must be the same as `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:Version`.